# Encrypting GCP Credentials file with Ansible Vault

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

I'm using the gcp_compute inventory plugin in Ansible 2.9.13 and everything is working OK using `auth_kind: serviceaccount` and `service_account_file: <somefile>.json`

My issue is that I don't want to store the service account file in plaintext. If I encrypt it with ansible-vault, the plugin does not seem able to read the file and it fails with the standard "stuffs broken, fail in a weird way" that inventory modules seem to do:

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inventory/ --graph --ask-vault-pass
Vault password:
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse <rootpath-redacted>/inventory/hosts_gcp_compute.yaml with auto plugin: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse <rootpath-redacted>/inventory/hosts_gcp_compute.yaml with yaml plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse <rootpath-redacted>/inventory/hosts_gcp_compute.yaml with ini plugin: Invalid host pattern 'plugin:' supplied, ending in
':' is not allowed, this character is reserved to provide a port.
[WARNING]: Unable to parse <rootpath-redacted>/inventory/hosts_gcp_compute.yaml as an inventory source
@all:
...<list of other inventory items excluding gcp_compute ones>
```

If I change nothing else other than decrypt the file referenced with `service_account_file` then the command runs fine and I get a full list of inventory.

Is there a way to get the gcp_compute inventory plugin to read the service account file via ansible vault? I can't find any documentation that shows storing the file encrypted, or a way to load it into a variable and pass that to the script or anything - I can't work out if there just isn't a way, or if I am trying to do things the "wrong" way.

The plan is for our ansible setup to be running in a docker container, which might be on any cloud provider's platform (gcp, aws etc) or on a dev's machine, so I can't assume that I'll have the GCE Metadata server providing a service account already, I'll need to provide one somehow. I would also rather avoid having a separate script running to do the decryption first, but if that's the only way then that's probably the path I'll take.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this exact same thing for the past day and a half. For simplicity, I *had* to get it to work and I tried so many different approaches until I finally stumbled upon a very simple trick:

```
gcp_cred_file_enc: "credentials.json.enc"
gcp_cred_file_contents: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', '{{ gcp_cred_file_enc }}') | from_json | to_json }}"
```

AND IT WORKS!! The `credentials.json.enc` file is simply the downloaded GCP credentials file named like so, and encrypted with `ansible-vault encrypt --vault-id=@prompt credentials.json.enc`

Now `gcp_cred_file_contents` can be used with `service_account_contents`:

```
service_account_contents: "{{ gcp_cred_file_contents }}"
```

.. and the inventories are created successfully!

Comment: Thanks so much! I needed this! Anyways, why the from_json to_json part? it works even without it

Comment: @Naramsim For me, it required `| from_json | to_json` to work. The problem may have been specific to my use case, or perhaps it was due to a bug somewhere that has since been fixed. The output of `gcp_cred_file_contents: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', '{{ gcp_cred_file_enc }}')` wasn't 100% JSON-compliant (I have forgotten specifically how) which the hack fixed. The decryption is, of course, preferable to use without it.

Comment: I can confirm that I've had this issue for the past like 10 hours, and strangely enough what seems to have fixed it was from_json | to_json. Extremely odd behavior there

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to encrypt the `credentials-file.json` contents as a string with `ansible-vault encrypt_string` ([doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-vault.html#encrypt-string)) and then use its `!vault | $ANSIBLE_VAULT;...` output to define `gcp_compute`'s [service_account_contents](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_inventory.html#parameter-service_account_contents) parameter (instead of using `service_account_file`), as seen in [this guide](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/ansible-vault-example-encrypt-string-playbook/#10_Ansible_vault_encrypt_string)'s step #10.